Including static .a Libraries in CMake Project
I am working on a project for STM32 in VSCode and I need to include libraries with the .a extension to be able to call their functions. I need help with configuring CMake. My current CMake setup looks like this, but it seems like my program cannot access the functions in libSTM32Cryptographic_CM4.a because I get errors like: undefined reference to cmox_hash_compute.
 add_library(crypto_sha INTERFACE)

target_include_directories(crypto_sha INTERFACE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} 
    inc
    inc/hash
    inc/cipher
    inc/drbg
    inc/ecc
    inc/mac
    inc/rsa
    inc/utils
    SHA_Implementation
)

target_sources(crypto_sha INTERFACE
    cmox_low_level.c
    SHA_Implementation/SHA_HASH.c
    lib/libSTM32Cryptographic_CM4.a
)


